# Google Web Designer distorting image sharpness

Tags: website-design, images, photo-editing, digital

I'm using Google Web Designer to create an animation. The program is awesome for the most part. The one area where it's a bit befuddling is with image quality.

Original images are usually quite large in terms of pixels (e.g. 15 megapixels). When I resize them with Google Web Designer, the image sharpness gets distorted - the quality often seems to go down when compared to the same image resized via Preview on Mac.

Attached are screenshots of the same picture resized to the same size in terms of pixels in both Preview and Google Web Designer.

Picture - resized in Preview

[image: Picture - resized in Preview]

Picture - resized in Google Web Designer

[image: Picture - resized in Google Web Developer]

**EDIT**

By resized I mean:

Preview: Resampling and creating a new file

Google Web Designer: Dragging the picture's boundaries inwards to make the picture smaller on the screen.

As an aside, I experimented with zooming out in Preview and noticed the quality is actually higher than when the image is downsampled. If this is the case, why doesn't preview use the same zooming algorithm when shrinking a picture?

Comment: What do you mean by "resized". Are you actually resampling these images, or are these simply zoomed out?  If the later, it's probably just a display issue. What happens when you actually output the file/images?

Comment: You can always resize it with an image editor that has a better algorithm. Gimp, Photoshop, Krita, Paint.net probably all work for it. I'm sure some online image resizers probably work too, and surely a lot of other programs. Then upload the resized image back into Google Web Designer so you no longer have to worry about quality loss. This is assuming that the program is actually using a crummy image resizing algorithm.